# How to make group of FloatingActionButtons in Android

Tags: android

How to make something like that(image linked) in android. I just need an idea.

http://beautifulpixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/tumblr-Android-Masthead-final.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these are the libraries for fab and fab menu.
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/173

or you can customize one of them and can create your own.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is a FloatingActionButton. May be its semi transparent activity with the buttons on it.